# Is it possible to recover a Cassandra node without a snapshot?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Offsite backups for Cassandra seem like a challenging thing.  You basically have to make yet another copy of ALL your data, including the copies of data that exist due to the replication factor.  Snapshots make backups easy when you don't mind storing it on the same disk that your node already uses.  I'm curious - in the event of a catastrophic failure of this disk, is it possible to recover the node using the nodes that the data was replicated to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can restore data on crashed node using a procedure in documentation - [Replacing a dead node or dead seed node](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceNode.html). It's for Cassandra 3.x, please pick your Cassandra version from a drop-down menu on the top of the page.

But please note that you still need to do backups if your data is valuable. If you using AWS you can use [this project](https://github.com/tbarbugli/cassandra_snapshotter) to backup Cassandra to S3 storage.

Comment: Thank you Deniszh.  We have intentions on moving to AWS early next year.  Once that is done I think real backups (I.E. on different hardware than the server the data is from) will be a lot easier.  In the mean time, we have the data on 3 different servers that each have two mirrored drives.  I think we will be safe with snapshots and incrementals being stored on those drives for now.  It is reassuring to know that I can restore a dead node from the nodes it is replicated to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for offsite or off-host backups, you can also look at opscenter from Datastax or [Talena](http://www.talena-inc.com) software (my company).  Both provide you the ability to backup your database locally or to S3.  As you may expect, you also have the ability to restore data in case of hardware failures, user errors or logical corruptions which the replicas will not protect you against.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible. Just execute in terminal "nodetool repair" on the node with missed data. It can take a lot of time. Also I would recommend execute repair operation on each node every month to keep your data always replicated because cassandra does not repairs data automatically (for example after node(s) falling).

Comment: I downvoted your answer nodetool repair does not replace a dead node.  Also, repairs can happen automatically if read repair is enabled.

Comment: @gsteiner You are right about `nodetool repair` not replacing a dead node, but read-repair does not repair the whole table so it cannot replace the occasional repair operation.